# JavaScript - all the possible combinations from arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Hey I have this example:

```
var arr = [['USA', 'Canada'], ['Food', 'Sports']];
```

and with this the result expected is:

```
arr = [
  ['USA', 'Food'],
  ['USA', 'Sports'],
  ['Canada', 'Food'],
  ['Canada', 'Sports']
];
```

The wrong way I did it was like this:

```
var newArr = [];
$.each(arr[0], function (i, item) {
  $.each(arr[1], function (i, thisItem) {
    newArr.push([item, thisItem]);
  });
});
```

But this will not work well when I added more items to the arr.

there is any way to do it recursive, no matter how many levels we have?

Comment: Your approach should certainly work if you had say two arrays of three items each.  What use case do you have in mind where you code would fail, and can you show this in your question?

Comment: Can you please share a sample for input and output with more than 1 level

Comment: Stack snippet is for **running code** only, I just edited your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is called `cartesian` product.

You can use `ES6` features in order to achieve this: `reduce` and `map` methods.

> In set theory (and, usually, in other parts of mathematics), a
>   Cartesian product is a mathematical operation that returns a set from
>   multiple sets.

```js
function cartesianProduct(array) {
  return array.reduce((a, b) =>
    a.map(x => b.map(y => x.concat(y)))
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []), [[]]);
}
console.log(cartesianProduct([['USA', 'Canada'], ['Food', 'Sports']]));
```

If you want to pass **arrays** as parameters, just use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
function cartesianProduct(...array) {
      return array.reduce((a, b) =>
        a.map(x => b.map(y => x.concat(y)))
        .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []), [[]]);
}
console.log(cartesianProduct(['USA', 'Canada'], ['Food', 'Sports']));
```

Comment: *there is any way to do it recursive*

Comment: @Rajesh being recursive is not an OP's requirement. OP probably just said (and used the tag) that because he thought that this would achieve his real requirement, which is *"no matter how many levels we have"*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado As per last comment, I assumed, OP is looking for a method recursively as he/she mentioned about more levels

Comment: This answer does deal with more levels and it is not (explicitly) recursive.

Comment: Thanks @Alexandru